# How to obtain accurate plot curves in Mathematica?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, plot

Run the following code In Mathematica:

```
r=6197/3122;
p[k_,w_]:=Sqrt[w^2/r^2-k^2];q[k_,w_]:=Sqrt[w^2-k^2];
a[k_,w_,p_,q_]:=(k^2-q^2)^2 Sin[p]Cos[q]+4k^2 p q Cos[p]Sin[q]
a[k_,w_]:=a[k,w,p[k,w],q[k,w]];
ContourPlot[a[k,w]==0,{w,0,6},{k,0,14}]
```

This gives me very inaccurate curves:

[image: The curves obtained from the code above are very inaccurate]

I have tried setting the `PlotPoints` and `WorkingPrecision` options of `ContourPlot` to 30 and 20 respectively, to no avail. You will also notice that the only numerical parameter, `r`, is an exact rational number. I don't know what else to try. Thanks.

Edit: The curves I expect to get are the three black ones (marked A1, A2, and A3) on the following picture

[image: Expected curves (the black ones)]

Comment: Maybe you can ask it at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @plaes: This is not a question about Mathematics. It is a question about Mathematica.

Comment: Can you include a picture of roughly what you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure about the picture and/or the definition for `a`? From the definition of `a` it follows that `a[k,w]==0` on `k==w` but that curve doesn't appear in your picture.

Anyway, assuming that the definition of `a` is right, the problem with plotting the contours is that in the domain `w^2/r^2-k^2<0`, both `p[k,w]` and `Sin[p[k,w]]` become purely imaginary which means that `a[k,w]` becomes purely imaginary as well. Since `ContourPlot` doesn't like complex valued functions only the parts of the contours in the domain `w^2/r^2>=k^2` are plotted.

Not that `Sin[p[k,w]]/p[k,w]` is real for all values of `k` and `w` (and it's nicely behaved in the limit `p[k,w]->0`). Therefore, to get around the problem of `a` becoming complex you could plot the contours `a[k,w]/p[k,w]==0` instead:

```
ContourPlot[a[k, w]/p[k, w] == 0, {w, 0, 6}, {k, 0, 14}]
```

**Result**

[image: contour plot of a/p==0]

Comment: You were right. I had a mistake in the definition of `a`. I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Dividing by `p` fixed it. I didn't even have to set PlotPoints, or anything! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I have got something very similar to what you expect by separate plotting of real and imaginary parts of the l.h.s. of the equation:

```
ContourPlot[{Re@a[k, w] == 0, Im@a[k, w] == 0}, {w, 0, 6}, {k, 0, 14},
  MaxRecursion -> 7]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your function gives complex numbers in the region of the contour lines you show.  Is that what you expect?  You can see the region that is real here:

```
ContourPlot[a[k, w], {w, 0, 6}, {k, 0, 14}]
```

[image]

I get something in some ways closer to your lines if I use:

```
ContourPlot[a[w, k] == 0, {w, 0, 6}, {k, 0, 14}]
```

[image]

Is it possible there is a transcription error?

(My apologies if this is unhelpful.)

Comment: There was a transcription error (pointed out by Heike in the answer above) and it's fixed now. However, it is `a[k,w]`, not `a[w,k]`, and there's no error there. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`p` ans `q` will be real valued only if `w^2 - k^2` and `w^2/r^2 - k^2` are both nonnegative.  `w^2 / r^2 - k^2` will only be nonnegative in the following area of your plot region:

[image]

Therefore everything else will be cut off by `ContourPlot`.  Perhaps you need to make some corrections to the equations (you only need the real part?  magnitude?)  I don't believe the curves Mathematica gives you are very inaccurate.  Otherwise the way to go to increase accuracy of the contours if increasing `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` (say, to 50 and 4).

Answer (score 1):

Try to play with the parametrization of your equations. For example, define `a=w^2-k^2` and `b=w^2/r^2-k^2`, then solve for `a` and `b` and map them onto `k` and `w`